# Does snapshot load time matters?

Tags: seo, google-search

Site content is generated via script and a [snapshot](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) scheme is implemented. Pages loading pretty fast but snapshots much longer since they are generated dynamicly. So does snapshot load time matters to SEO ranking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated at the top of [that page](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more): "This recommendation is officially deprecated as of October 2015."

Your time is probably better spent focusing on improving the load time for real visitors, and then letting Google crawl that same content. As [stated by Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html): "If you pre-render pages, make sure that the content served to Googlebot matches the user's experience, both how it looks and how it interacts."